# Batch nested loop doesn't work properly with errorlevel

Tags: loops, batch-file, nested, errorlevel

I have a problem with a nested loop and usage of errorlevel. I want to delete files on multiple computers with batch files. For this I have a batch file that iterates through the computers and calls another batch files that deletes the files. On some computers I want to delete the files in a second folder. 
The first part of the code works as expected, but the second part with the nested loop doesn't work. the code is:

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
REM %1 is a parameter from the calling batch file
FOR %%A IN (M:\Folder\) DO del /Q "%%A" 2>&1 1> NUL | find /V "" 1> NUL 2>&1 & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (1> NUL ver) ELSE (2> NUL SET =)
IF !ERRORLEVEL! == 1 ( 
    ECHO !ERRORLEVEL!
) ELSE (
    ECHO OK
)
FOR %%N IN (%computers%) do (
IF %%N EQU %1 (
        FOR %%A IN (M:\Folder2\) DO del /Q "%%A" 2>&1 1> NUL | find /V "" 1> NUL 2>&1 & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (1> NUL ver) ELSE (2> NUL SET =)
        IF !ERRORLEVEL! == 1 ( 
            ECHO !ERRORLEVEL!
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO OK
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail about what else you've tried and what you see when its "not working"?

Comment: If you take a look at the usage information for the `Del` command, _(by entering `Del /?` at the Command Prompt)_, you'll note that the `/Q` option is for deletion of multiple files. As you're only removing files one by one, there is absolutely no need to include an unnecessary option. Additionally, there are other options which may come in useful, if you're really trying to remove all files in a directory you have permissions to delete from; e.g. `Del /A /F /Q "M:\Folder\*" "M:\Folder2\*">Nul 2>&1` should try to delete all files in more than one directory. Please explain your actual task.

Comment: @Compo: `2>&1 1>NUL` sends STDERR to (wherever STDOUT currently goes to), **then** redirects STDOUT to NUL. Prove: `dir  nonexistent.file 2>&1 1>NUL`

Comment: TBF @Stephan, I knew that, what I should have asked was why not simply use `1>Nul` or `>Nul`, if hoping to pipe errors only. Also if you wanted to know if files weren't deleted, why not just do `If Exist "M:\Folder1\*" Del /A /F /Q  "M:\Folder1">Nul 2>&1&&(Echo Okay)||Echo one or more files failed to delete`? If you needed to know which, if any, failed to be deleted `Dir /A-D "M:\Folder1"` would list those remaining after the delete command has run, which you could use with or instead of the 'failed' message

Comment: thanks for the answers so far. I think my problem is not deleting the files or using STDOUT or STDERR. I want to delete folder1 on all computers and folder2 only on particular computers defined in the variable %computers%. The problem is the second (nested) loop isn't executed. Something seems to break the loop.